# Author Page Create Link to Page That Lists All Author's Posts?

Tags: author, author-template

In my author.php page, I'm wanting to create a link that sends the user to a list of all posts by that author. I thought this was a built in function of WordPress, but having trouble finding the function and its syntax.

`the_author_posts_link()` seems to just link back to the author page.

```
<div class="outerContainer longFormContainer">
   <div class="contentContainerNarrow longFormContent">

      <?php 
          $post_author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
      ?>

       <?php if( get_field('author_img', 'user_' . $post_author_id) ): ?>
          <img class="alignleft" src="<?php the_field('author_img', 'user_' . $post_author_id); ?>" width="200" alt="<?php the_author(); ?>" />
       <?php endif; ?>

       <?php
          if ( get_the_author_meta('description') ) : 
             echo '<p>';
             echo the_author_description();
             echo '</p>';
           endif;
        ?>

        <p>View all posts by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_author_posts_link()` points precisely to your author.php template, and it's normally used in posts (inside the loop).

So to get the author's posts list, you have two options:

**1)** Show the author posts in the same author.php template, simply using the normal loop (because this is just the query loaded in this template). By the way, you have a [nice example in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Sample_Template_File).

**2)** Generate a different template that shows only (as you want) the author's posts list, querying as follows:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author_name' => 'nicename' ) ); //author 'user_nicename'
```

Probably it will be a good point to load the nicename as a `custom_query_var`

Hope it helps!